# local cache folders after map reduce jobs completed are not deleting

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running map-reduce job in LocalRunner mode. All jobs are completed successfully however, local cache folders after completion of map-reduce jobs are not deleting automatically. We have set the property "hadoop.tmp.dir" value as "/tmp".

Could anyone please help to fix this issue

Comment: I believe this is expected behavior. They will not automatically be deleted.

Comment: When we are running the map-reduce job on hadoop all cache folder and files gets deleted automatically. However, when we are running as local runner mode files getting deleted but empty folders are exists as it is.

Comment: HDFS/YARN might have settings to control this, but I don't think same applies for local runner